# Oh no! Something went wrong! While starting the system after installing Kali Linux

Tags: system-installation, virtualbox, kali-linux, gdm

I am trying to install a virtual machine running Kali (Formerly backtrack) 1.0.7 In 64 bit. My host machine is a 64 bit MacBook pro running 10.7.5. I am using Oracle VirtualBox version 4.3.12. The install goes perfectly, but after installing it, I get an error when I try to boot. Here is a screen shot.

[image]

I hit New virtual machine, selected 64 bit debian and created an 8gig dynamically allocated VDI. In settings, I have selected the correct ISO, and checked PAE/NX under processor. After doing all of this, the live mode works perfectly. Installing, I do everything the default way, and everything goes perfectly. After I finish the installation, it asks me if I want to boot. When I do, I get the above error.

I have done lots of research trying to figure it out, but none of the advice I can find online has helped. Here is everything that someone has said will fix that didn't work for me.

> "Enable PAE/NX in settings"

Made absolutely no difference.

> "When you get that error, press Ctl+Alt+F1, this will take you to the
>   terminal tty1, now login as root:
>
> `login: root password: "your password"..`
>
> Once as root, start the X's: `startx`
>
> You will get your desktop...This might be a xauthority issue or dbus
>   issue when loadind, perhaps a daemon.
>
> Try this first and if it works, try doing this: dpkg-reconfigure
>   gnome-shell, then reboot."

```
command: startx not found.
```

Needless to say it didn't bring me to the desktop.

I tried fixing the problem of the startx command not being found by reading through [this](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/startx-'command-not-found'-225710/) forum.

I will refer to what they said I should try.

> try typing /usr/X11R6/bin/startx

```
-bash: /usr/X11R6/bin/startx no such file or directory
```

I tried all of the following commands:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install x-windows-system
apt-get install x-window-system
```

All 3 resulted in this

```
Bus errorackage lists... 1%
```

Comment: Please indicate which VM+version you're using (virtualbox I think). When you created the VM and gave it a name, did you select _Debian 64-bit_ or similar in the last drop down? Sometimes it will make a difference. How did the install go? How come the install seems incomplete and the package manager is in such a [state](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+question/186641)? Have you modified repository sources manually? Usually when it [works](http://kanishkashowto.com/2013/09/03/how-to-install-kali-linux-in-virtualbox-step-by-step-guide/) it doesn't have such issues.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Quite simple. 8GB of disk isn't enough for this version of Kali Linux. Use VBoxManage to resize the virtual disk, and GParted to expand the filesystem.

Comment: Yep, that was the problem, thankyou!

Comment: @David could you please update your answer with more details.

Comment: @KasiyA, I didn't end up using VBoxManage. Instead I started from scratch and allocated more memory in the VDI. I hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

As I was attempting to install Kali 2.0 on VMware I was running into the same issue. Startx was not found, and even upon manually installing it would not work. The one thing that worked for me was to enable virtualization in bios. This is usually a problem that occurs with VirtualBox for me, but this time it resolves the issue with Kali 2.0 on VMware.

Answer (score 1):

My situation was different. I was installing on a new laptop. My configured VM had plenty of memory and disk yet I still had this issue.

What I eventually found was that since it was a new laptop the bios configuration did not have virtualization turned on.

Once I enabled this in the bios my VMs worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

i had some problems with gnome-shell so i decided to install xfce4

```
apt-get install kali-defaults kali-root-login desktop-base xfce4 xfce4-places-plugin xfce4-goodies
```

then

```
update-alternatives --config x-session-manager
```

Comment: nope, for some reason i had problems with it, so i switched to xfce4 instead

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with VB 5.2.6 on macOS High Sierra.  I had to disable the 3D acceleration to get it to boot fully to user login screen.  This only happend **after** installing the extension pack on my Debian guest.

VB 5.2.4 worked fine (with 3D acceleration enabled).

Downgrading to VB 5.2.4, installing the 5.2.4 extensions, and reenabling 3D acceleration fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score -1):

apt-get update
apt-get install x-windows-system
apt-get install x-window-system

This worked for me from advanced mood.

Comment: This will not increase the allocated size of the virtual disk (which is the issue that the user in the question has).

Answer (score -3):

I also had the same problem and I was not able to type password, because nothing happens as I type password. So I downloaded a different version of kali which supports virtual box and it worked for me.

Answer (score -4):

this might work..  It did work for me:

```
# apt-get update
# apt-get install xorg
```

and then try `startx`

Answer (score -4):

I had been facing same issue, tried very diffrent ways which don't work.
Eventually I've just typed:

```
exit
```

And logged again with my credentials. 
Works for me, was that simple ;)